# Whats the proper way to have a form submit data in a stateless react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a stateless react component that is a little pop up. It takes some data from the user, and passes that back to its parent, where it executes the work.

What is the best way for this component to have a handleSubmit() function, that takes the user input, and sends it back to the parent?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css";

const Transfer = (props, token, web3) => {
  return (
    <div className="modal is-active">
      <div className="modal-background" onClick={props.onClick} />
      <div className="modal-card">
        <section className="modal-card-body">
          <div className="content">
            <h1 className="title"> Transfer Tokens </h1>
            <p className="has-text-danger">
              Requires that you are the owner of the token you are transferring
            </p>
            <p className="subtitle">How it works</p>
            <p className="">
              Enter the ID of the token you want to transfer, the address to
              whom its going to, and thats it!
            </p>
            //problem area
            <form onSubmit={props.onClickSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor="text">Address to recieve token</label>
              <input
                name="Address"
                className="input is-info "
                required="true"
              />
              <label htmlFor="number">Token ID</label>
              <input
                className="input is-info"
                name="Token ID"
                type="number"
                required="true"
              />
              <a className="button is-pulled-right">Submit</a>
            </form>
          </div>
        </section>
        <footer className="modal-card-foot is-clearfix">
          <a className="button" onClick={props.onClick}>
            Cancel
          </a>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Transfer;
```

I pass in as a prop, onClickSubmit, in my parent component, and that contains the logic for what I'm trying to do.

Very new to stateless react components

Comment: You most likely want to use a stateful component and store the input values in state and use that as argument for the `onClickSubmit` prop function.

Comment: That was my solution, but this is a very small component that is simply taking a few pieces of data and thats it. It seems like the perfect component to be stateless? IF this component cannot be stateless, then I feel like I'm doing stateless components wrong?

Comment: You can't use state or refs in a stateless component, so there are really no tools for you to accomplish what you want without turning it into a stateful component. If you have a component that just depends on the props given to it, stateless components are a great fit. But there is really no point in trying to force stateless components if they don't fit your use case.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the feedback. Any resources you can share that go into the deeper and newer side of react, and not the basics? I get the basics, but when trying to dive into new/deeper things its hard to learn

Comment: I personally don't know much more than the techniques listed in the [Main concepts](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) and [Advanced Guides](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html) parts of the documentation. The rest I feel is just experience with certain libraries and JavaScript in general.

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult to accomplish what you want with a stateless component since you cannot use either `refs` or `state` in a stateless component. You can think of a stateless component as a pure function that returns a piece of UI depending on the `props` you give it.

You could instead use a stateful component and e.g. store the input values in `state` and call the `onClickSubmit` prop function with this `state` when the user submits the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build stateless forms component, I send you a lib that I'm working on:

[react-distributed-forms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-distributed-forms)

This allow you to build your Transfer Component this way, (pay attention to use Input instead of input and Button instead of button):

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css";
import { Input, Button } from "react-distributed-forms";
const Transfer = (props, token, web3) => {
  return (
    <div className="modal is-active">
      <div className="myForm">
        <label htmlFor="text">Address to receive token</label>
        <Input name="Address" className="input is-info " required="true" />
        <label htmlFor="number">Token ID</label>
        <Input
          className="input is-info"
          name="Token ID"
          type="number"
          required="true"
        />
        <Button name="submit" className="button is-pulled-right">
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Transfer;
```

And then in your parent Component, wherever it is in the hierarchy, you simply do:

```js
<Form onSubmit={({ name }) => { console.log(name); }} onFieldChange={({ name, value} ) => { console.log(name, value); }}>

  ...whatever
  
  <Transfer />
  
  ...whatever

</Form>
```

onFieldChange will receive every input change.
onSubmit will receive the attribute "name" on the Button when you click it.

react-distributed-forms use React context API, so you don't have to pass directly props, it just works. Is built for really dynamic forms...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone googling this same question and looking for an answer, I applaud your quest to keep your React UI components stateless. Separation of concerns will help greatly in testing and when creating a component library in something like Storybook.

Here's a great (and short) post I found on why and how to keep your components stateless.

https://dev.to/kuvambhardwaj/creating-custom-forms-in-react-with-stateless-inputs-2k8k

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34332827)